# index a list in a Python for loop

Tags: python, nested-loops

I'm making a for loop within a for loop. I'm looping through a list and finding a specific string that contains a regular expression pattern. Once I find the line, I need to search to find the next line of a certain pattern.  I need to store both lines to be able to parse out the time for them. I've created a counter to keep track of the index number of the list as the outer for loop works. Can I use a construction like this to find the second line I need?

```
 index = 0
 for lineString in summaryList:  
    match10secExp = re.search('taking 10 sec. exposure', lineString)
    if match10secExp:
       startPlate = lineString
       for line in summaryList[index:index+10]:
           matchExposure = re.search('taking \d\d\d sec. exposure', line)
           if matchExposure:
               endPlate = line
           break
    index = index + 1
```

The code runs, but I'm not getting the result I'm looking for.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to include the outer loop's code as well.

Comment: Instead of manually counting, you can do this: `for index,line in enumerate(summaryList):`

Answer (score 1):

```
matchExposure = re.search('taking \d\d\d sec. exposure', lineString)
```

should probably be

```
matchExposure = re.search('taking \d\d\d sec. exposure', line)
```

Comment: I think you're right, but I fixed that and it still won't produce the right output. I put a print line in the innermost if statement and nothing is being printed.

Comment: Is the second line you're looking for always 3 digits for the exposure time? (Also, you can use `\d{3}` instead of `\d\d\d`.)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact needs, you can just use an iterator on the list, or two of them as mae by [itertools.tee](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools.tee#itertools.tee).  I.e., if you want to search lines following the first pattern *only* for the second pattern, a single iterator will do:

```
theiter = iter(thelist)

for aline in theiter:
  if re.search(somestart, aline):
    for another in theiter:
      if re.search(someend, another):
        yield aline, another  # or print, whatever
        break
```

This will *not* search lines from `aline` to the ending `another` for `somestart`, *only* for `someend`.  If you need to search them for both purposes, i.e., leave `theiter` itself intact for the outer loop, that's where `tee` can help:

```
for aline in theiter:
  if re.search(somestart, aline):
    _, anotheriter = itertools.tee(iter(thelist))
    for another in anotheriter:
      if re.search(someend, another):
        yield aline, another  # or print, whatever
        break
```

This is an exception to the general rule about `tee` which the docs give:

> Once `tee()` has made a split, the
>   original iterable should not be used
>   anywhere else; otherwise, the iterable
>   could get advanced without the tee
>   objects being informed.

because the advancing of `theiter` and that of `anotheriter` occur in disjoint parts of the code, and `anotheriter` is always rebuilt afresh when needed (so the advancement of `theiter` in the meantime is not relevant).